# Display time series data in a table without weekday and time of the dates

Tags: output-formatting, time-series, display

I have downloaded some data:

```
mydata = FinancialData["SP500", {{2014, 10, 23}, {2016, 10, 22}}]
```

I would like to see them in a table where the date is formatted without the weekday and the time.

For example, I would want something like this:

```
-------------------
2014-11-5 | 2023.57
-------------------
2014-11-6 | 2031.21
-------------------
2014-11-7 | 2031.92
-------------------
```

Currently, I have only managed to display the data in a table but not to format the date:

```
Normal[TimeSeriesWindow[assetsUS, {{2014, 11, 5}, {2014, 11, 7}}]] // Grid
```

Is there a way to print it out in a table with borders as shown in the example above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert the `DateObject` to a formatted string with `DateString`. "ISODate" formats the string as YYY-MM-DD.  `MapAt[...,{All, 1}]` applies it to the first element.

```
MapAt[DateString[#, "ISODate"] &, 
  Normal[TimeSeriesWindow[
    mydata, {{2014, 11, 5}, {2014, 11, 7}}]], {All, 1}] // Grid
```

2014-11-05  2023.57
2014-11-06  2031.21
2014-11-07  2031.92

Or

```
MapAt[DateString[#, "ISODate"] &, 
  Normal[TimeSeriesWindow[
    mydata, {{2014, 11, 5}, {2014, 11, 7}}]], {All, 1}] // 
 Grid[#, Frame -> All, FrameStyle -> Directive[Gray, Dashed]] &
```

[image]